# Having a little trouble with my RegEx today

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am having a bit of a time with my RegEx today

`\('[\d',]+`

In the string:

```
INSERT INTO `order_status_histories` VALUES ('3602','52efabe9-5f8c-4512-a994-3227c63dd20e','1','','Order recieved','2014-02-03 16:47:05','2014-02-03 16:47:05'),('3603','52eff713-54fc-4be0-9389-68d5c63dd20e','1','','Order recieved','2014-02-03 22:07:47','2014-02-03 22:07:47'),('3604','52effd1a-bc14-4095-97fd-6d46c63dd20e','1','','Order recieved','2014-02-03 22:33:30','2014-02-03 22:33:30')
```

As you can see this is an insert statement, however, that 1st value is the ID of the record, which I do  not need inserted, so I am attempting to find all of them, and simply blank them out...  but I need to #1 get that number, the 2 `'` characters, and the `,` after it in order to do so... so I though that I would start with the opening `(`.

The regex I posted in here is grabbing what I need, but a bit extra... it seems to be grabbing this `('3670','5304` (for instance in that first insertable record)

How can I do what I need here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about `\('\d+',` - so explicitly looking for digits, then `'` then `,`

Answer (score 0):

the character class [\d',] isn't doing what you want - its matching both the opening quote of the second field and the decimal digits after it until you get to a letter